# Generic spinner / processing message in a browser

Tags: javascript, ajax

Most browsers show a spinner in the tab at the top of the page when a page is loading. It's a standard way of showing that the browser is in the process of fetching something.

I'm writing a client-side ajax app, and would like a generic way of showing that an ajax call is in process. Rather than finding some element on the page and sticking a spinner on it, is there a generic way in javascript to access the browser's spinner?

Comment: Usually browsers automatically spin it with ajax calls

Comment: @php_nub_qq: they don't

Comment: You can change the css `cursor: wait`

Comment: @Jasen thumbs up for coolest idea ever

Answer (score 0):

There are only two things I can think of that are similar to what you want.

#1: changing the cursor (idea from @Jasen in the comments of the question): you can simply set the `cursor` css property of the body to `wait` whenever you have an Ajax request running.

#2: use a hacky iframe. Basically, create a server side page that loads headers, but doesn't end the request. When you want the loader symbol, simply create an invisible or off-screen iframe with that url, and remove it when the request completes

Unfortunately, there is no "official" api that defines a simple way to do this (e.g. there is no such thing like `window.startLoader()` or `window.stopLoader()`, for example)

Comment: There are a couple of issues with using the cursor. 1) You'd need to cache the cursor state before you begin your request, then restore it after the request finishes. 2) The browser might decide to change the cursor while waiting for your request. 3) The _wait_ cursor is only visible while hovering over that DOM element. 4) To make a robust cursor solution is more work than doing a gif background spinner.

Comment: but, the OP said that he/she didn't want to have a simple loader image. They wanted to have a better solution. And if they don't find the cursor solution acceptable, they can just try the iframe idea. After all, that's what they asked for. They never required that there be anything with the cursor. That's just extra

Comment: Yes, but that's why I didn't want to post an answer for a technique I don't really like.